# Performance Issues

Tags: 18.04, performance

I do not use Ubuntu a lot because when I do on both my laptop and desktop it freezes for hours sometimes when I am in the middle of something. For example last night I was coding and I lost what I worked on because I had to restart the computer.

Is this normal? If not does anyone have an idea to help fix it or make it faster?
FYI it is not like I am running big applications this happens when I am just using one tab open on Firefox or checking my email on Thunderbird...

The computer specs are
Dell Vostro 470 w/ 1TB HDD and 4GB RAM.

[/var/log/syslog result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R17a1.png)

Comment: Add the contents of `/var/log/syslog` just before the system crashed.

Comment: This is much too unspecific to be answered. Please add more details.

Comment: Computer make and model and/or specs will be useful.  Some hardware have known bugs.  Freezing is problem that there should be a solution for, it is not normal.  High temperature can also cause freezing, but usually a shutdown.  Might just need a bios update or something as easy.

Comment: I dont do much programming but for simple text files I use Kate (it is more capable than that though) , which does an auto  backup that can be restored on crashes which, for me, is frequent.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I added it to the post.

Comment: @HuHa my desktop is a Dell Vostro 470 w/ 1TB HDD and 4GB Ram. It also happens on my laptop and that is a Lenovo G50-45 w/ 1TB HDD and 8GB RAM.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text output, but the text formatted as code.

Comment: So the problem appears to be with Microsoft Teams and/or SSL?